# Are there any cars in the street? x Are there cars in the street?

Tags: grammar

As a language learner I've been taught that the grammatically correct question is *Are there any cars in the street?* But I'd like to know if *Are there cars in the street?* would be acceptable without sounding awkward.

Comment: Most native speakers would probably talk about _traffic_, not cars in the street.

Comment: If I omitted "any" I'd probably use the definite article before "cars". That would mean that I'm asking about some particular cars and not about cars in general.

Comment: Traffic refers to moving cars. Any cars parked against the curb are also in the street.

Comment: Cascabel,  fsdfsd  Actually my question is about the possibility of dropping *any* in questions such as: *Are there students in the classroom?* Does it sound awkward?

Comment: Voting to close & move to ELL because (in his/her own words) Op is "a language learner" & this question is more appropriate for our sister site English Language Learners.

Answer (score 0):

"Are there cars in the street?" is a grammatically correct sentence and sounds natural when spoken in conversation.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was checking. :)

Comment: It doesn't sound natural to me (in British English): I would say "Are there *any* cars in the street?"